# NUC 5CPYH + Intel 3165 + Ubuntu 15.04 or 14.04. Here's how.

Tags: kernel, 15.04, intel, intel-nuc

This page describes how to get the Intel 3165 wireless card working on Ubuntu 15.04 on the Intel NUC 5CPYH.

To fix this problem:

1. Check the linux kernel you are using
   $ uname -r
   Even if you've installed Ubuntu 15.04, it's still using the 3.19 Kernel.
2. Right now, Intel is only supporting the 3165 hardware with firmware for 4.1+. So you need to upgrade to 4.1. It's easiest by using wget to get the right version for your hardware, and for whatever kernel you want to use. I wanted the most recent stable release. Use wget to get them. (I can't post the links on how to do this because the forum won't let me until I have a reputation established.)
3. Download the appropriate firmware for the 3165:
   https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#firmware

You'll see it's called "iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz"
Unpack it, and then navigate into the unpacked directory.

4. MOST IMPORTANT: THIS SOLVES THE ISSUE:
   Look inside the unpacked directory, and rename the two ucode files to match those that Ubuntu is looking for (at least in my case):

   - iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode renamed to     iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode
   - iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode renamed to  iwlwifi-3165-13.ucode
5. Move those two renamed files to /lib/firmware

Suddenly, wireless.

BAM! You're done.

Comment: Well unfortunately this is wrong, but I don't have a 10 reputation so I can't include the links to make it complete. I fixed this problem by upgrading to 4.2 kernel and then I could connect to the wireless access points. So you can ignore all the finding/downloading/installing of firmware and specialized drivers.